# Can I see the card I draw before deciding to activate Dawn of Hope a second time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have one [Dawn of Hope](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDawn%20of%20Hope%5d) and two [Soul Warden](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSoul%20Warden%5d) on the field. Another creature enters the battlefield, triggering both Soul Wardens' effects. Since each Soul Warden causes a separate life-gaining event, I know that I can activate the effect of Dawn of Hope twice, to draw two cards.

But can I activate it once, look at the card I draw, and only then decide whether or not to activate it a second time? Or must I decide it all at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can and will (by how the game mechanically works) see 1 card before choosing to use it a second time.

What will happen is as follows:

1. Both Soul Warden Triggers go on the stack, the order of which doesn't matter for this case.
2. Both players pass priority, causing the top of the stack to resolve (i.e. you gain 1 life from the first Warden trigger).
3. Dawn of Hope will trigger because you have gained life and will go on the stack, above the 2nd Warden trigger.
4. Both players pass priority
5. You can now resolve Dawn of Hope, where you decide if you want to pay for it then draw a card if you do pay for it.
6. Both players pass priority.
7. Second Warden trigger finally resolves and will follow steps 3-5.

For completion's sake: if you have multiple life-linkers attacking or blocking, they all will trigger Dawn of Hope, putting a trigger on the stack for each one. Each trigger will also resolve one at a time just as above.